# Can I reclaim ETH from the DAO using a different wallet?

Tags: synchronization, the-dao, thedao-refund

I have started up my old ubuntu machine after taking a break from crypto for a while. I had bought ETH and DAO tokens before the attack. I would now like to reclaim my ETH from the DAO but unfortunately I cannot sync the wallet on my old ubuntu machine even after leaving it for weeks.

I now want to use a newer (MacOS) machine in the hope that this will sync faster - I have my keystone and my password.

Will my contract with the DAO show up on the new wallet and will I be able to withdraw using this wallet?

Answer (score 2):

You can withdraw your DAO refunds as long as you have your original keystore and password.

You can check your available DAO to ETH, DAO to ETH ExtraBalance and DAO to ETC refunds using the tool at https://refunds.thedao.fund/ .

Instructions for withdrawing your refunds can be found at https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/The_DAO_Refunds .

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm currently waiting for my new wallet to sync, so I can process the withdrawal. 

I have tried using the below guide to withdraw my ETH however it got stuck at step 1 and would not load the index page with #The-Dao added:

https://medium.com/curator-multisig-phf-official-channel/dao-token-holders-come-claim-your-money-b428f186572a

My understanding is that this would be a way to withdraw DAO without waiting for the new wallet to sync?